# angularjs same textarea to edit multiple elements

Tags: textarea, angularjs, keyup

I have this case where I set a current item from a list and I need to use a textarea to edit that element's value.
Because of some constraints I have to use a keyup event but I don't think that's a problem.

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/terebentina/Euj2C/

1. click on first/second buttons - it works, it changes the text in the textarea to the value of each element.
2. change the text in the textarea to something
3. click on the first/second buttons again - the textarea is not updated anymore. If you look in console, you can see that it switches between the elements, it's just that the textarea is not updated anymore.

Any suggestions? this is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 1):

I know there is a better way modifying your directive to do this but as a quick fix for now you can try binding your [textarea](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3atextarea) to a [ngModel](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel) value that is just a copy of the current text in the selected element:

```
<textarea keyup="" ng-model="keyupText"></textarea>
```

With this in as your `current` function:

```
$scope.current = function(idx) {        
    $scope.current_element = $scope.elements[idx];
    $scope.keyupText = $scope.current_element.value;
    console.log('current is', $scope.current_element.value);
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mAHST/) for an example.

Comment: this doesn't work because the ng-model updates the model for me (instantly) instead of my keyup directive. Like I said, I need it to be keyup. My fiddle is a simplified version of what happens in the actual app. In the app I need to update the model only when the user stops typing, not instantly, which is why I can't use ng-model.

Comment: I see makes sense I'll delete my answer and try and take a look later.. in the meantime someone will probably be able to help!

Comment: Hmm..yeah, it works but do you at least know why does it behave like that in my fiddle? I would like to understand why, if you can shed some light.

Comment: Just a guess is that the {{current_element.value}} evaluation binding to the UI is broken once something is entered into the textarea (since it's not a regular binding using ngModel). Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Euj2C/1/ if you click the buttons and then update one side and click a button the text will continue to change properly in the second textarea.

Comment: turns out that {{}} is an alias for ng-bind, which is supposed to be unidirectional (from model to view) though it isn't in my fiddle. From digging through the official docs and into the angular source code, I think the way to go is by using ngmodelcontroller in my keyup directive but I was unable to make it work. If you could make such an example work, it would be great. For now I made it work like you suggested in the answer...